# Regular Expression - Match only separator within parentheses

Tags: regex

I have a program which parses CSV files. Unfortunately the program cannot handle if the separator is inside parentheses. Now I would like to find a regular expression that finds the separator if it is within parentheses.

```
Name;Zip;Comment
Smith,12345;"Weird comment with ; inside"
```

The following Regex returns the whole comment field but I only want the ; character within the parentheses

```
("[^;]*;[^;]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try some regular expressions like this

```
r\".*(;).*"\
```

In this case, regular expression will match with entire comment. However, Capturing Group 1 (section inside parenthesis) will match with `;` inside double quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the possibility to specify which capturing group should be used. The whole match of the regular expression will be replaced with a character of my choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following *regex* to capture the entire comment and replace the semi-colon by using captured group :

```
(".*?)(;\s)(.*?")
```

­

```
input        >>  Name;Zip;Comment
                 Smith,12345;"Weird comment with ; inside"
match        >>  (".*?)(;\s)(.*?")
replace with >>  $1$3
output       >>  Name;Zip;Comment
                 Smith,12345;"Weird comment with inside"
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/OZmh8H/1)